# an error occur when running a c++ script in cygwin

Tags: c++

I tryed to run the following code in my cygwin

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
const int NR=2005;
int n,m;
bool arr[NR][NR];
int mx_jx(int x){
    int up[NR][NR],lf[NR][NR],rt[NR][NR];
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=m;j++)
            up[i][j]=1,lf[i][j]=rt[i][j]=j;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(int j=2;j<=m;j++)
            if(arr[i][j-1]==x)lf[i][j]=lf[i][j-1];
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(int j=m-1;j>=1;j--)
            if(arr[i][j+1]==x)rt[i][j]=rt[i][j+1];
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=m;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]!=x)continue;
            if(i>1 && arr[i-1][j]==x){
                up[i][j]=arr[i][j-1]+1;
                lf[i][j]=max(lf[i][j],lf[i-1][j]);
                rt[i][j]=min(rt[i][j],rt[i-1][j]);
            }
            ans=max(ans,(rt[i][j]-lf[i][j]+1)*up[i][j]);
        }
    return ans;
}
int main(){
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=m;j++){
            int tmp;
            scanf("%d",&tmp);
            arr[i][j]=(int)tmp;
            if((i+j)&1)arr[i][j]=!arr[i][j];
        }

    printf("%d",max(mx_jx(0),mx_jx(1)));    
    return 0;
}
```

It passed the compile(0 warning,0 error), but when I tried to run it with the following input

```
4 4
0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
1 1 0 1
```

It says "Command terminated"

these code could run correctly on other platform, how can I solve this problem on cygwin? thanks a lot

Comment: "1 warning, 0 error" should be always read as "1 error".

Comment: You might be getting a stack overflow because you don't have 48 megabytes of stack space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer from [user3684240](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3684240/user3684240) is valid and it is definitely an issue with your code, more likely you have Stack Overflow due to allocating numerous huge arrays on stack and in global memory area.

You should use `std::vector<std::vector<int>` instead of plain C arrays.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> up(NR, std::vector<int>(NR, 0));
std::vector<std::vector<int>> lf(NR, std::vector<int>(NR, 0));
std::vector<std::vector<int>> rt(NR, std::vector<int>(NR, 0));
```

It is not very well optimized, but it's simplest solution I can provide.

---

For that `bool` array though, `std::vector` might behave... strange. I cannot give 100% guarantee that it will work if you simply substitute `bool[][]` with `std::vector<std::vector<bool>>` without testing it properly, because `std::vector<bool>` is optimized for memory and it has certain quirks that one should be aware of when using it.

You can try and see if that array of bools in global memory works (after changing arrays in `mx_jx` to vectors), maybe it does and you don't have to change it. If it doesn't, you can try to change to vector of vectors, then it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in that line:

```
scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
```

`%d` reads ints, but your array is of type `bool`. This leads to a memory error.

An easy way to fix it would be:

```
int read_value;
scanf("%d", &read_value);
arr[i][j] = read_value;
```

As an additional hint: If you enable compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`), the compiler will tell you about those kinds of mistakes.

Comment: I have modified my code, but it didn't solve the "Command terminated" problem